# shutil.move doesn't delete source files

Tags: python, move, shutil

Newish Python guy here.  I've written what I thought would be a fairly simple script to extract the creation date metadata from photos and video and move them to a new folder based on year and month.  I'm using PIL for picture and hachoir for video metadata.

For the most part I've got it working until I actually use shutil.move.  At that point all the jpg's move to the new folders just fine.  But all the videos are being COPIED.  The original files are being left in the source folder.

My assumption is that some process that I invoke during the script is still accessing the video file and not letting it be deleted.  Can anyone tell me what I'm messing up, and how I can release these video files to be moved?

========================

```
import os.path, time, sys, shutil
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
from hachoir_core.error import HachoirError
from hachoir_core.cmd_line import unicodeFilename
from hachoir_parser import createParser
from hachoir_core.tools import makePrintable
from hachoir_metadata import extractMetadata
from hachoir_core.i18n import getTerminalCharset


def get_field (exif,field) :
  for (k,v) in exif.iteritems():
     if TAGS.get(k) == field:
        return v



for picture in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):

    if picture.endswith(".jpg") or picture.endswith(".JPG"):
        print picture
        rawMetadata = Image.open(picture)._getexif()
        datetime = get_field(rawMetadata, 'DateTime')
        datedict = {'year' : datetime[0:4], 'month' : datetime[5:7]}
        target = datedict['year']+'-'+ datedict['month']

        if not os.path.isdir(target):
            newdir = os.mkdir(target)
        if picture not in target:
            shutil.move(picture, target)


    if picture.endswith('.mov') or picture.endswith('.MOV') or \
         picture.endswith('mp4') or picture.endswith('.MP4'):

        picture, realname = unicodeFilename(picture), picture
        parser = createParser(picture, realname)
        rawMetadata = extractMetadata(parser)
        text = rawMetadata.exportPlaintext()
        datedict = {'year' : text[4][17:21], 'month' : text[4][22:24]}

        target = datedict['year']+'-'+ datedict['month']

        dest = os.path.join(target, picture)

        if not os.path.isdir(target):
          newdir = os.mkdir(target)

        if picture not in target:
            try:
                shutil.move(picture, dest)
            except WindowsError:
                pass
```

Comment: a bit of a comment, if you use `glob` you can probably save yourself a good number of cycles comparing filenames. `for picture in glob.glob("*.jpg"): # this is case-insensitive`. Alternatively, do `if picture.lower()[-4] in ('.mov','.mp4'): # for movies`

Comment: Thanks adsmith, I'll look into glob. Still trying to learn all these different modules. lol

Comment: I added a print statement immediately following the WindowsError exception and it actually gets invoked everytime shutil.move runs. It's like it copies the file to the folder and THEN checks to see if it's there and sees that it is. Could THAT be what's preventing shutil.move from finishing the move process?

Comment: This was kind of verbose for a comment. I added it as an answer since it will probably lead to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `in` operator says whether items are in collections (e.g. an element in a list) or strings are substrings of other strings. It doesn't know that your string variable `target` is the name of a directory, nor does it know anything about checking directories to see if files are in them. Instead, use:

```
if os.path.exists(dest):
```

Comment: Ooh good catch! Although it seems like the `try/except` block would render that `if` catch redundant. Besides, EAFP

Comment: Although it's interesting to note that OP is copying images to `"path/to/dir/"` but copying movies to `"path/to/dir/file.mov"`

Comment: I changed the bit that Peter suggested. Thanks for that.  Still not deleting video files though.

Comment: adsmith, honestly I think that was just my latest incarnation of trying to make this work. I'm pretty sure I had them both operating the same way in the first attempt and changed it to this to see if that would work.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what exactly is failing without a decent error code. Use this in your `except` block to get more answers:

```
except WindowsError as e:
    print("There was an error copying {picture} to {target}".format(
        picture=picture,target=target))
    print("The error thrown was {e}".format
        (e=e))
    print("{picture} exists? {exist}".format(
        picture=picture, exist=os.exists(picture))
    print("{target} exists? {exist}".format(
        target=target,exist=os.exists(target))
```

Note that much can be said for the `logging` module for errors like these. It's rather outside the scope of this question, though.